# How to speed up soap call response time in magento?

Tags: magento, meteor, soap

My Meteor application contains meteor-soap to call Magento's soap API. I am getting the soap response approximately after 12sec. How to reduce the response time?

Answer (score 1):

Enable api cache in **Magento backend panel**, it will reduce your response time.

Comment: I have done Enabling WSDL cache in my magento admin panel but still the response time is 5-6sec. Is there any other way to make it even faster?

Comment: Now only one way now, optimize Database server.